# Symfony2 form layout - variables source

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

Here's the main form layout twig file:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig

An example:

```
{% block form_widget_simple %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% set type = type|default('text') %}
    <input type="{{ type }}" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} {% if value is not empty %}value="{{ value }}" {% endif %}/>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_widget_simple %}
```

I wonder where varaibles like "type" or "value" come from?

The goal I'm trying to achieve is to set form row's label as a placeholder in the widget. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Details how to override Template for Form field you will find [here.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-a-template-for-the-field)

If you trying to change labels to placeholders all you need is to change way of rendering your forms. Remove `form_widget(form)` and switch to render every separate form field:

```
{# ... #}
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_errors(form.email) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.email, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'E-mail address'|trans }}) }}
</div>
{# ... #}
```

This example generate input for email field and html/css classes for bootstrap.
And shows you how `{{ type }}` and `{{ value }}` are passed - by `attr` array.

Good Luck!

Comment: Making it work with placeholders is not a big deal to be honest. The question is more about where all the variables come from.

Comment: @TaruoGene you mentioned that this is a goal... Read about overriding templates for form fields. And [Form Themes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#what-are-form-themes). You will find that `{{ type }}` and `{{ value }}` are passed to templates by Symfony\FrameworkBundle:Form and related with entity attribute value and Forms Builder label of Form Type.